# LangChain and MessagesPlaceholder, memory is not added to the prompt

Tags: langchain, amazon-bedrock

This is the code im struggling with

```
    template = """The following is a friendly conversation between a knowledgeable helpful AI and a human.
The AI is talkative and provides lots of specific details from it's context included between the <document> and </document> tags.
If the AI does not know the answer to a question, it truthfully says it does not know.

<document>
{context}
</document>

Conversation:
    """

    prompt_instructions = SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template)
    prompt_instructions = prompt_instructions.format(context=pdf_text)
    messages = [
        prompt_instructions,
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{input}"),
    ]
    qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)

    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
        human_prefix="Human", ai_prefix="AI", return_messages=True
    )
    conversation = ConversationChain(
        prompt=qa_prompt, llm=chat, verbose=True, memory=memory
    )

    return conversation


def run_chain(chain, prompt):
    return chain({"input": prompt})


def clear_memory(chain):
    return chain.memory.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    formatted_text = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]", "", convert_pdf_to_txt("test.pdf"))
    removed_excessive_newlines = re.sub(r"\n\s*\n", "\n\n", formatted_text)

    chain = bedrock_chain(removed_excessive_newlines)
    resp = chain.predict(input="Hello there!")
    print(resp)
    chain = bedrock_chain(removed_excessive_newlines)
    resp = chain.predict(input="Does Tim know anything about New Relic?")
    print(resp)
```

Somehow this actually did work yesterday, then I cant figure out what I have changed but now I cant get the prompt to include the history from memory, `MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history")`

Can someone help me spot what I'm doing wrong?

I have tried out different memory_key's for ConversationBufferMemory but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is that the MessagePlaceholder is not getting the history. This is because you are not passing it in anywhere. Normally, you would pass it in when calling `chat_prompt.format_prompt`, but that call is hidden by the `ConversationChain`. You should be able to pass the history param in like so:

```
chain.predict(input={'input':'Hello there!', 'history':[human_message, ai_message]}
```

With human_message and ai_message being whatever history you want to pass in. I am not sure on this answer however, so if it does not work for you, please post what running `chain.input_keys` gives you.

**Note:** By passing in the memory parameter in the `ConversationChain`, you shouldn't need to worry about passing in any additional history. You would only want to use the `MessagesPlaceholder` if you have messages not captured by the chain's previous calls (ie. memory).

Reference:
[Langchain message prompt](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/prompts/prompt_templates/msg_prompt_templates)
[Langchain ConversationChain](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chains/langchain.chains.conversation.base.ConversationChain.html)